# Como colocar vários formatos nos pontos da minha PCA pelo ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de colocar formas diferentes nos pontos do gráfico de uma PCA gerada pelo ggplot2 por exemplo (masculnos= quadrado, femininos= triângulo...).

Answer (score 2):

Se você ajustou o PCA da forma a seguir:

```
ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])
```

Pode obter os valores de cada um dos componentes fazendo:

```
ir.pca$x
```

Portanto, para plotar com o ggplot, eu faria assim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data_frame(
  PC1 = ir.pca$x[,1],
  PC2 = ir.pca$x[,2],
  Species = iris$Species
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = Species)) + geom_point()
```

Veja que adicionei um argumento `shape = Species` para indicar que a forma dos pontos do gráfico deveria ser diferente dependendo da espécie.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que seu banco de dados deve ser diferente, mas a princípio é só ir adaptando este código.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena você colocar os `library()` na resposta, pode ser que algumas pessoas não saibam quais pacotes você está usando.

Answer (score 2):

O pacote FactoMiner em combinação com o pacote factoextra foram pensados para contemplar essa situação. Note que quali.sup, na função PCA, e habillage, na função fviz_pca_ind, são a variável categórica.

Ademais, como a base é o ggplot, você pode customizar como quiser.

```
ir.pca<-PCA(iris,quali.sup = 5,graph=F)
fviz_pca_ind(ir.pca,geom="point",habillage = 5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Também é possível fazer no base R.

Exemplo:

```
ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4]) 
plot(ir.pca$x[,1], ir.pca$x[,2], pch = as.numeric(iris$Species),
     xlab = "PC1", ylab = "PC2")
legend("topright", pch = unique(as.numeric(iris$Species)), 
       legend = unique(iris$Species))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]